# Passive Mod Rewrite Regular Expression

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm rather new with Regular Expressions in general. Basically, I want to rewrite a url to accept either of these urls

```
create/
create/?action=blah&foo=bar

manage/
manage/?action=blah&foo=bar
```

The base page would be `create.php` or `manage.php`. Here is my current expression that works without the GET parameters.

```
RewriteRule ^(manage|create)/$ $1.php?$2 [L,QSA]
```

What can I add to passively accept the get parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(manage|create)/(.*)$ $1.php$2 [L,QSA]
```

That should give you an optional set under `$2`

Comment: That will add the '?' twice, btw.

Comment: I'm torn about how to handle this... On the one hand, I can handle the optional `?` explicitly; on the other, I can remove it from the rewrite and allow it to be entered when it exists. This might also encourage some error handling in other places.